# Facebook Graph API: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request instead of error inside

Tags: facebook-graph-api, bad-request

I have a code that make a Get request to Facebook Graph API to get business account.

This is code:

```
var facebookBusinessAccountId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook_business_account_id"];
                            facebookRestUrl += "&access_token=" + acct.AccessToken;

                            facebookRestUrl = facebookRestUrl.Replace("{0}", facebookBusinessAccountId);

                            var request = WebRequest.Create(facebookRestUrl);
                            request.Method = "GET";
                            request.ContentType = "application/json";

                            var response = request.GetResponse(); (Error here)
```

The URI look like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/1x8xx4005xxxxxx?fields=business_discovery.username(yess_cub){biography,id,ig_id,profile_picture_url,username,website}&access_token=EAAJ..
```

It should be return error like this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid user id",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 110,
    "error_subcode": 2207013,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Cannot find User",
    "error_user_msg": "The user with username: yess_cub cannot be found.",
    "fbtrace_id": "BMEAcyYOZf9"
  }
}
```

But error : `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request` is what I get

Could anyone please help me?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Start removing fields, until you find the culprit …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an idea and catch the inner exception from try/catch statement

It should be like this:

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
   {
      string jsonMessageString = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
}
```